# How do i make a scrollable list like google tasks ui in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm stuck with making a scrollable list like Google Task app when you reach end of the list if any task is completed it shown in another list with custom header as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi2vS.jpg), I'm using sliver

```
Widget showTaskList() {
  final todos = Hive.box('todos');

  return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: Hive.box('todos').listenable(),
      builder: (context, todoData, _) {
        int dataLen = todos.length;
        return CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              floating: true,
              expandedHeight: 100,
              flexibleSpace: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 10,
                    top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 17),
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Text(
                  'My Task',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate:
                  SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, int index) {
                final todoData = todos.getAt(index);
                Map todoJson = jsonDecode(todoData);
                final data = Todo.fromJson(todoJson);
                return MaterialButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: IconButton(
                          icon: data.done
                              ? Icon(
                                  Icons.done,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                )
                              : Icon(
                                  Icons.done,
                                ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            final todoData = Todo(
                                details: data.details,
                                title: data.title,
                                done: data.done ? false : true);
                            updataTodo(todoData, index);
                          }),
                      title: Text(
                        data.title,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            decoration: data.done
                                ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
                                : TextDecoration.none),
                      ),
                      subtitle: Text(data.details),
                      trailing: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
                          onPressed: () {
                            todos.deleteAt(index);
                          }),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }, childCount: dataLen),
            ),
          ],
        );
      });
}
```

ShowTaskList is called on

```
Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              
              child: showTaskList()
            ),
            
          ]),
        ),
```

I tried `OffStageSliver` to make an widget disappear if no complete todo is present but that did not work and also can not use any other widget on CustomScrollView because that conflict with viewport because it only accept slivers widget.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM9vy.jpg) what i have achieved  so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try use `ScrollController` put it on `CustomScrollView` and listen to it's controller in initState like this :

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        // If it reach end do something here...
      }
    });
  }
```

I suggest you make bool variable to show your widget, initialize it with false and then after it reach end of controller call setState and make your variable true, which you can't call setState in initState so you have to make another function to make it work like this:

```
  reachEnd() {
    setState(() {
      end = true;
    });
  }
```

Put that function in initState. And make condition based on your bool variabel in your widget

```
if(end) _yourWidget()
```

Just like that. I hope you can understand and hopefully this is working the way you want.